# how can I connect loopback with elasticsearch,

Tags: elasticsearch, loopbackjs

I tried to follow loopback-connector-es, but I was not able to connect to an existing elastic searh, maybe a tutorial where it shows an example for simple search using a model other that user.

thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you seeing when you try to connect?

Comment: I can run the connector now , I was missing the index and type field in datasources.json , I am trying to mimic exists _search/exists?q=user:user but I do not  know how to change the path in the connector-es when I do Model.find(searchCriteria, func(){..})
I see it says starting request { method: 'POST', path: '/model/_search' ...  but I need to say path: '/model/_search/exists
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-exists.html

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to check existence using 2 fields I couldnt find a way to use " model instance exists by ID "
_search/exists?q=name:name and state:live